# Can't acess Image<Bgr, byte>.Data property in C# emgucv

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I could access each pixel of a Gray image using `Data[,,]` but cannot do so for Bgr image.
I have written the following code:

```
Image<Bgr, byte> currentFrame = capture.QueryFrame();
Image<Gray, byte> grayFrame = currentFrame.Convert<Gray, byte>();
Byte gray = grayFrame.Data[0, 10, 0];
Byte blue = currentFrame.Data[0, 10, 0];
```

which throws an exception: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

I checked by adding breakpoint and the result was this:

```
currentFrame.Data is nul
grayFrame.Data has 3d array
gray has value 71
```

and then the next line caused error

Why is the currentFrame.Data, which should have been a 3d array, null? How can I access Image.Data property for Bgr image?

I am using emgucv 2.2.1. Same problem occured with 2.1 version.

Thanks for any help

---

What I have found is quite surprising.

```
Image<Bgr, byte> currentFrame = capture.QueryFrame();
byte b;
try
{
   b = image.Data[0, 0, 0];            //Line (A)
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ MessageBox.Show("Before Convert : "+ex.Message); }         

image = image.Convert<Bgr, byte>();

try
{
   b = image.Data[0, 0, 0];           //Line (B)
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ MessageBox.Show("AfterConvert : "+ex.Message); }
```

In the above code: Line (A) throws exception "Object refence not set to an instance of an object". But after adding the code

```
image = image.Convert<Bgr, byte>();
```

Line(B) runs smoothly without any exception.

Does anyone know why this is hapenning?

Comment: What language is that? Is that C#? Add the appropriate tag so you can get help from the folks that understand your code.

Answer (score 3):

*[Though it is very late to answer, I am posting this for future reference.]*
Recently I faced the same problem. I could not access pixel values of an image returned by `QueryFrame` through `Data` property. But after applying any operation (e.g. resize, convert) resulting image is accessible. The reason behind this and the solution is quite simple.

`Data` property of an image returned by `QueryFrame` is always null. Its image data is stored in unmanaged memory, therfore is not accessible thorough `Data` property. To access the pixel values of a frame, you just have to clone it.

```
Image<Bgr, byte> currentFrame = capture.QueryFrame();
Image<Bgr, byte> frame = currentFrame.Clone();
// now access using Data property
byte b = frame.Data[0,0,0];
byte g = frame.Data[0,0,1];
byte r = frame.Data[0,0,2];
```

Answer (score 0):

capture.QueryFrame() returns null, which you try to access on the last line. I'd look inside that method. I'm guessing .Convert is an extension method, and that that method checks for null and returns something that is not null.

Comment: The capture.QueryFrame() has returned valid frame beacuse I am able to display the frame in imageBox (as imageBox1.Image = currentFrame; works properly)

Answer (score -1):

Heyy there,try to add .xml file in your .../bin/Debug. Then type in your ProcesFrame Method: //haar is HaarCascade haar = new HaarCascade("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");